# how to create shared object .so with android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

according to this link https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk

i made all installation process above , here the problem is how to create this *.so file and where in eclipse , or how to build it ??

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Cygwin** tool to create shared object file from the c files.

If you don't know how to create applications by using android NDK, just check below link, a good tutorial is available.

[How to use Android NDK](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)

I don't know anything about the link you specified. I followed the above tutorial, its working fine. I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you've already compiled it successfully you will find that where the shared libraries are created.

For example: Check $(Project) > libs > areabi-v7a directory.

Install        : libImageTargets.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libImageTargets.so
Install        : libQCAR.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libQCAR.so

Comment: thanks the problem is solved it is about opening the cygwin then change directory the target then build